# Cloning with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I have a form that allows users to refer friends. I want to add a link below the two input fields, "friend email" and "friend name", that will clone "friend-box" one time and add it below. In addition, the name attribute of "friend email" and "friend name" are `name="friend_email[0]"` and `name="friend_name[0]"` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436606/how-to-process-tell-a-friend-data). What's the best way to clone and increment the subscript? Here's the code:

```
<div class="friend-box">

    <div class="field">
        <span><label for='friend_name'><strong>Friend's Name *</strong></label> </span>
        <input id='friend_name' name='friend_name[0]' type='text' />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <span><label for='friend_email'><strong>Friend's Email *</strong></label></span>
        <input id='friend_email' name='friend_email[0]' type='text' />
    </div>

</div>
```

What's the best way to do this? One of the problems I had for example, is that when I cloned "friend-box" once and then twice, it obviously cloned it exponentially. So I'm guessing I need to have an ID number in there as well and increment it. Or, which is another method I saw, is to clone the "friend-box" when the page loads and keep cloning it from memory.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/K8hhW/5/

You do not need to worry about incrementing the numbers in the brackets, the form does this automatically for you.

Comment: You might want to clear the inputs in case they were filled when cloning.

Comment: I do not think that I do, as the inputs are cloned into a var on page load.

Comment: Wow, this is really great! The reason I was referring to the index in my form is that it ensures that the 5th item in the email array would correspond to the 5th item in the name array. Isn't it trickier to validate and trying to prevent those get out of alignment?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the index [0], as long as you put [] the browser will automatically increment the index.

As for your question, here's how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/EJv4g/3/

Basically, I added a `div.friend-boxes` which wraps all friend boxes. I use jQuery to obtain the first friend box, clone it then reset the input field values (in case they were filled). I then append it to the `.friend-boxes` element.

You can change the `append` to `prepend` if you want it to be prepended.

Hope this helps!

- Christian

Comment: You're not resetting the inputs with `.val()`, which just returns the value of the first input. I'd use a hidden copy (outside of the form so it doesn't get submitted) for cloning.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm tired. lol. I agree you could either keep a copy hidden or run `.val('')` on each input. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/EJv4g/3/

Comment: You do realize every post has your name automatically attached to it right? No reason for an <ul><li>name</li></ul>